# RIAK Node does not Start after changing IP

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, erlang, riak, riak-cs

I am in the process of setting up a Riak Cluster on Raspberry Pis. 
Unfortunately I get the following error message after changing the IP address. 
Versions I used:
Debian Jessie (Raspberry PI)
riak (Github Clone Mar2017)
riak-cs2.1.1
stanchion-2.1.1

Using this guide I tried to change the IP addresses in the various .conf files. 
https://docs.riak.com/riak/kv/latest/using/cluster-operations/changing-cluster-info/index.html

```
Works on 127.0.0.1:

$ ~/riak/rel/riak/bin/riak-admin test
Successfully completed 1 read/write cycle to 'riak@127.0.0.1'


Error Message (after changing IP:192.168.178.61):

sudo ./riak console
config is OK
-config /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/app.2020.01.02.23.37.52.config -args_file /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2020.01.02.23.37.52.args -vm_args /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2020.01.02.23.37.52.args
Exec:  /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/bin/../erts-5.10.3/bin/erlexec -boot /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/bin/../releases/2.2.3/riak               -config /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/app.2020.01.02.23.37.52.config -args_file /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2020.01.02.23.37.52.args -vm_args /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2020.01.02.23.37.52.args              -pa /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/bin/../lib/basho-patches -- console
Root: /home/pi/neu/riak/rel/riak/bin/..
Erlang R16B02_basho10 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true] [frame-pointer]

[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,['riak@192.168.178.61',[]],[{file,\"orddict.erl\"},{line,72}]},{riak_core_capability,renegotiate_capabilities,1,[{file,\"src/riak_core_capability.erl\"},{line,441}]},{riak_core_capability,handle_call,3,[{file,\"src/riak_core_capability.erl\"},{line,213}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,585}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,239}]}]},{gen_server,call,[riak_core_capability,{register,{riak_core,vnode_routing},{capability,[proxy,legacy],legacy,{riak_core,legacy_vnode_routing,[{true,legacy},{false,proxy}]}}},infinity]}}}}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: ./log/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,['riak@192.168.178.61',[
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/basho/riak/issues/999

martinsumner commented 3 days ago:

I might expect to see this if you hadn't done the step of either renaming (or deleting the contents of) the ring directory. Did you do this?

Also can you confirm if you're in the single-node or multi-node renaming scenario?

Ei3rb0mb3r commented 1 minute ago:

Many thanks for the quick feedback!
The error has been solved after I deleted the ring directory files.

```
   ../riak/rel/riak/data/ring/ rm -rf *
```